# Tensorflow - shuffling at "batch-level" instead of"example-level"

Tags: tensorflow, batch-processing, shuffle

I have a problem that I will try to explain with an example for easier understanding.

I want to classify oranges (O) and apples (A). For technical/legacy reasons (a component in the network) each batch should have either only O or only A examples. So traditional shuffling at example-level is not possible/adequate, since I cannot afford to have a batch that includes a mixture of O and A examples. However some kind of shuffling is desirable, as it is a common practise to train deep networks.

These are the steps that I take:

- I first need to convert raw data/examples into TFRecords.
- I shuffle the order of the raw examples, and then I create separate TFRecords that contained either only the shuffled O examples, or only the shuffled A examples. Let's call this "**example-level**" shuffling. This is something that takes place offline and only once.
- At this point I have "clean batches": O-baches that contain only O examples, and A-batches that contain only A examples.
- I do not want to first feed the network with all the O-batches and then with all the A-batches sequentially. This would probably not help much in convergence.
- Can I shuffle these batches on the "**batch-level**", i.e. without affecting their interior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `Dataset` api it's fairly straightforward. Just zip the `O` and `A` batches, then apply a random selection function with `Dataset.map()`:

```
ds0 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0])
ds0 = ds0.repeat()
ds0 = ds0.batch(5)
ds1 = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1])
ds1 = ds1.repeat()
ds1 = ds1.batch(5)

def rand_select(ds0, ds1):
    rval = tf.random_uniform([])
    return tf.cond(rval<0.5, lambda: ds0, lambda: ds1)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset()
dataset = dataset.zip((ds0, ds1)).map(lambda ds0, ds1: rand_select(ds0, ds1))
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
ds = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(5):
        print(sess.run(ds))

> [0 0 0 0 0]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [1 1 1 1 1]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
  [0 0 0 0 0]
```